# Calculating the integral of $\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{(y+e^x |\sin(\pi x)|)^2}$ over $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty)$.

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I was working with some integrals and found the next one:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\left(y+e^{x}|\sin(\pi x)|\right)^{2}}\, dx \right)\,dy$$I need to calculate the value of that integral, but I really don't know how to procced. The tools that I can use is the Fubini theorem for multivariable calculus for improper integrals. My attempt:
If we can justify the equality (maybe with Fubini but I really don't know how) $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\left(y+e^{x}|\sin(\pi x)|\right)^{2}}\, dx \right)\,dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\left(y+e^{x}|\sin(\pi x)|\right)^{2}}\, dy \right)\,dx$$ then it is easy since$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\left(y+e^{x}|\sin(\pi x)|\right)^{2}}\, dy \right)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{-\sin(\pi x)}{e^x|\sin(\pi x)|+y } \ \Big|_{0}^{\infty}\right) dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{e^{x}|\sin(\pi x)|}\, dx$$But this last integral looks hard. Any idea from here? Maybe works to split the integral over the intervals where $\sin(\pi x)$ is positive and the part where $\sin(\pi x)$ is negative. Notice that in $[0,\infty)$, we have that $\sin(\pi x)\geq 0$ is grather or equal than zero in the intervals of the form $[2n,2n+1]$ with $n\geq 0$ and $\sin(\pi x)\leq 0$ in the intervals of the form $[2n-1,2n]$ with $n\geq 1$. It is true that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{e^{x}|\sin(\pi x)|}\, dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{2n}^{2n+1} \dfrac{1}{e^x} \, dx+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{2n-1}^{2n}  \dfrac{-1}{e^{x}}\, dx?$$If we calculate the integrals and the series then we can calculate in a easy manner the integral, but we need to justify the change of order integration and the equality with the series. How can I do?

Comment: Everything works because of absolute convergence (which is [easy to check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions)).

Comment: @metamorphy Can you elaborate? Please. I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(y+e^x|\sin(pi x)|)^2}dx\right)dy\\
&=&\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(y+e^x|\sin(pi x)|)^2}dy\right)dx\\
&=&\int_0^{\infty}\frac{-\sin(\pi x)}{y+e^x|\sin(pi x)|}\Big|_0^{\infty}dx\\
&=&\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(|\sin(pi x)|}dx\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_n^{n+1}e^{-x}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{|\sin(\pi x)|}dx
\end{eqnarray}
Setting $s=x-n$, we get
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1e^{-n-s}\frac{\sin(\pi n+\pi x)}{|
\sin(\pi n+\pi x)|}ds\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1/e)^n\int_0^1e^{-s}ds\\
&=&\frac{-e^{-s}}{1+e^{-1}}\Big|_0^1\\
&=&\frac{1-e^{-1}}{1+e^{-1}}=\frac{e-1}{e+1}.
\end{eqnarray}